# Assign values to all columns in 2D array in one Verilog statement

Tags: multidimensional-array, verilog

I would like to assign value to an array - mem. it has 16 rows and 16 col. 
each element is 2 bit wide. 
i would like to initialize each row of an array like this. if i am initializing 4th row of the array, then each value should be stored in respective column. so 0 will be in 15th col, 2 will be in 12th col, etc. I do not want to store values column by column. 
but below code is giving me an error. please can anyone help me here. thanks so much.

```
module test2;

reg  [1:0] mem [15:0][15:0];

wire [1:0] icon;

assign icon = mem[4][4];

mem[4][15:0] = 16'h0002000000000000; 

$strobe("%b", icon);

endmodule;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a for-loop inside an initial block:

```
module test2;
parameter initial_value = 16'b0001000000000000; 

integer i;
reg  [1:0] mem [15:0][15:0];
wire [1:0] icon; 
assign icon = mem[4][4];

initial 
  for ( i=0 ; i<=15; i++)
    mem[4][i] = initial_value[i];

always begin #10 $strobe("%b", icon); end

endmodule;
```